# How to launch .bat file after Gradle build. Sign and reinstall app from .bat

Tags: android, gradle, android-signing

I was struggling with a problem where I wanted to use Gradle to execute .bat script after .apk build that signed the application with platform key, and reinstalled it on the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folder structure

[image]

1. File instruction.bat content

> java -jar "..\app\build\outputs\apk\signapk.jar"
>   "..\app\build\outputs\apk\platform.x509.pem"
>   "..\app\build\outputs\apk\platform.pk8"
>   "..\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk"
>   "..\app\build\outputs\apk\signed.apk"
>
> adb install -r "..\app\build\outputs\apk\signed.apk"
>
> adb shell am start -n
>   com.your.package/com.your.package.MainActivity

2. Add this to your build.gradle -

> task signAndInstall(type: Exec) {
>       def finalPath = projectDir.toString() + '\build\outputs\apk\instruction.bat'
>       commandLine = [finalPath] }
>
> android {
>       applicationVariants.all { variant ->
>           variant.assemble.doLast {
>               signAndInstall.execute()
>           }
>       } }